# AWS ApiGateaway Cloudformation: I have a problem with JWTConfiguration when creating the authorizer

Tags: aws-cloudformation

Creating a Gateaway API via AWS Cloudformation I have a problem with JWTConfiguration when creating the authorizer.

```
Authorizer:
   Type: 'AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Authorizer'
   Properties:
     Name: VSTORES_Api_CognitoAuthorizer
     ApiId:  !Ref VCloudApiGateway
     AuthorizerType: JWT
     IdentitySource: 
       - '$request.header.Authorization'
     AuthorizerResultTtlInSeconds: 3600
     JWTConfiguration:
       Audience: 
         - xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
       Issuer: https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-xxxxxxx
```

I get the following error:

> Property validation failure: [Encountered unsupported properties in
> {/}: [JWTConfiguration]]

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-apigatewayv2-authorizer-jwtconfiguration.html) it looks like your formatting is correct. I suggest ensuring your JWT value is compliant with RFC 7519 and able to be decoded using a website similar to https://jwt.io/